# python 2d list problem with assigning value

Tags: python

I have a question regarding 2d lists in python after initilizing the list when I assign a value to an index of list I will get all the indexes assigned with the value
I'm really confused
can someone explain why this is happening
also how should I fix this issue

```
class_list = [[0] * 3] * 10
print(class_list)

class_list[2][1]  = 10
print(class_list)
```

and this is result:

> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0,
> 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] [[0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0,
> 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0],
> [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

***Numpy***

```
import numpy as np

class_list = np.array([[0] * 3]*10) 
print(class_list)

class_list[2][1]  = 10
# class_list.tolist() # if you want to use lists only.
print(class_list)
```

You will get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[np.zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

```
import numpy as np

class_list = np.zeros((10, 3))
class_list[2][1]  = 10
```